# Removing the duplicate entries from a list by editing the list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Have a list `arr = [1,3,4,5,2,3,4,2,5,7,3,8,1,9,6,2,1,2,1,3,4,3,4,6,9]`
want to remove the duplicate values so that the original list should contains single instances of all elements. Do not want to create a extra list and append the elements from list. Also do not want to use inbuilt "set".

Tried to do that with some code as below:

```
l = len(arr)
for x in range(l):
    for y in range(x+1,l):
         if arr[x] == arr[y]:
            del arr[y]
```

Tried the above code and its throwing error

```
"IndexError: list index out of range"
```

What I understand is whiling deleting the value the size of the list is changing for which its throwing the error. So I made the below changes. But still its failing with same error:

```
l = len(arr)
for x in range(l):
    for y in range(x+1,l):
         if arr[x] == arr[y]:
            t = y
            del arr[y]
            y = t - 1
```

Can some one help me out on this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Those lines won't make the slightest difference due to scoping. Anyway, now you see why strategies involving `set()` or the creation of a second `list` are popular.

Comment: any special reasons why you don't want to use set?

Comment: homework no doubt :P

Comment: @danidee::: no special reasons for not wanting to use set or a second list creation. Just want to check if there is any other way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make the code more efficient by caching the length of the list in the local variable `l`. However, that is not helpful because the list is being trimmed inside the loop, and you are not keeping the cached length variable in sync.

```
for index in range(len(arr)-1,0,-1): 
    if arr[index] in arr[:index]:
        del arr[index]
```

By going *backwards* through the array and looking for earlier occurrences of each element, you can avoid having to worry about the length of the list changing all the time.

This method also preserves the order in which elements occur in the original array. Note the instruction is to only remove duplicates (a.k.a. subsequent occurrences).

For example the list `[9,3,4,3,5]` should reduce to `[9,3,4, 5]` as the second occurrence of `3` is considered a duplicate and should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

```
>>> set(arr)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) #Just to compare it with the results below.
>>> arr = [1,3,4,5,2,3,4,2,5,7,3,8,1,9,6,2,1,2,1,3,4,3,4,6,9]
>>> arr.sort()
>>> arr
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
>>> for i in arr:
    while arr.count(i) > 1:
        del arr[i]


>>> arr
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Another approach is to find, after sorting your list, the length of the sublist to delete for each number:

```
>>> arr = [1,3,4,5,2,3,4,2,5,7,3,8,1,9,6,2,1,2,1,3,4,3,4,6,9]
>>> arr.sort()
>>> arr
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
>>> for i,j in enumerate(arr):
        del arr[i+1:i+arr.count(j)]
>>> arr
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: `arr[:] = [ele for i, ele in enumerate(arr) if ele not in arr[:i]]` would be a nicer way to use enumerate

Comment: @PadraicCunninghan .. By nicer you mean *readable* or *efficient* ?

Comment: a bit more efficient but I  would not really consider either to be an efficient way to tackle the problem,  it would also keeps the order the elements are encountered.

Comment: @IronFist has illustrated three ways (counting the initial `set` as well) to remove duplicates, but all of these involve sorting the original list, thereby destroying the original sequence of elements. This is a side-effect which the OP did not ask for. The sort operation is in itself computationally expensive too (even the `set` constructor performs a sort if the input list contains only numbers). If efficiency is important (who knows how large these lists are going to be?) then in-place editing of the original list is the way to go and doing only the *minimum* amount of work along the way.